# ESXi 4.0 on Proliant DL380 g4

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant

Ok. I am using an HP Proliant DL380 g4 with 6 x 36GB drives. The drives RAID 1 in groups of 2. Anyways, everything I have read online says that ESXi 4.0 should work on this server; however, when I boot to the USB flash drive (used Rufus to make it bootable), I get the following error... "menu.c32: not a COM32R image." Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Jordan

Comment: Use the CD drive. Better yet, avoid installing on an 8 year-old server. Why *would* you expect USB boot to work?

Comment: Well, I had already read a few articles that said it should work...so I figured it would. Also, this is my first "real" server so I'm trying to learning as much as possible. Thanks for your helpful response.

Answer (score 1):

Use a newer version of syslinux (or whatever you use to make the bootable usb drive that uses syslinux eg Rufus (as you mentioned) or UNetbootin), or use a DVD if you have a drive.

Comment: Thanks Ramruma. I was fed up so I just ended up burning the ISO image on a CD-R using Roxio...still kinda bugs me that I could not get that dang thing to work using Rufus. For future reference, my settings in Rufus were FAT32 and I also tried NTFS. The cluster sizes were 8192 bytes and 4096 bytes respectively. Neither of these configurations worked...should these have been different?

Comment: The dvd worked: let's stop there. Your error message suggests a com32R image was found when looking for a com32 image but there is no real point in working out which of your rufus/syslinux/iso layers was older or newer than the rest.